# tensorflow object detection API 独自データの転移学習にてOOMが発生してしまう

Tags: python, tensorflow

機械学習の初学者です。
tensorflow object detection API を使用して独自データの転移学習をしたいと思っています。

学習には独自データセットとして
800x600の画像を100枚ほどカメラで撮影して
"labelImg"でアノテーションをつけて作成したものを使用しています。

データセットは、tensorflowで使用するtfrecord形式に変換した状態で
訓練用：test_train.record(9MB)
検証用：test_val.record(3.7MB)
となっています。

学習時のチェックポイントファイルは、Tensorflow detection model zooから
「ssd_resnet_50_fpn_coco」の学習済モデルをDLして使用しています。
[Tensorflow detection model zoo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md)

下記のコマンドで学習を開始しました。

```
PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH=foo/test/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync.config
MODEL_DIR=/foo/test
NUM_TRAIN_STEPS=30000
NUM_EVAL_STEPS=2000
time python3 object_detection/model_main.py \
    --pipeline_config_path=${PIPELINE_CONFIG_PATH} \
    --model_dir=${MODEL_DIR} \
    --num_train_steps=${NUM_TRAIN_STEPS} \
    --num_eval_steps=${NUM_EVAL_STEPS} \
    --alsologtostderr
```

その後、以下のエラーメッセージが出力されて学習が開始できませんでした。

> 2019-02-01 15:11:58.709085: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:279] ****************************************************************************__**_____***********____
>   2019-02-01 15:11:58.709106: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1318] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:386 : Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,256,160,160] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
>       return fn(*args)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
>       options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
>     File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
>       run_metadata)
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[64,256,160,160] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
>        [[Node:FeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_50/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/Conv2D = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](FeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_50/resnet_v1_50/pool1/MaxPool, FeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_50/block1/unit_1/bottleneck_v1/shortcut/weights/read)]]
>   Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
>        [[Node: total_loss/_4689 = _Recvclient_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_22359_total_loss", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]]
>   Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

実行時のconfigファイルは以下を指定しています。

```
# SSD with Resnet 50 v1 FPN feature extractor, shared box predictor and focal
# loss (a.k.a Retinanet).。

# See Lin et al, https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.02002
# Trained on COCO, initialized from Imagenet classification checkpoint

# Achieves 35.2 mAP on COCO14 minival dataset. Doubling the number of training
# steps to 50k gets 36.9 mAP

# This config is TPU compatible

model {
  ssd {
    inplace_batchnorm_update: true
    freeze_batchnorm: false
#    num_classes: 90
    num_classes: 2　　　#クラス数を変更
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
        use_matmul_gather: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    encode_background_as_zeros: true
    anchor_generator {
      multiscale_anchor_generator {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
        anchor_scale: 4.0
        aspect_ratios: [1.0, 2.0, 0.5]
        scales_per_octave: 2
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 640
        width: 640
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      weight_shared_convolutional_box_predictor {
        depth: 256
        class_prediction_bias_init: -4.6
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            random_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.01
              mean: 0.0
            }
      }
          batch_norm {
            scale: true,
            decay: 0.997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
        num_layers_before_predictor: 4
        kernel_size: 3
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn'
      fpn {
        min_level: 3
        max_level: 7
      }
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.0004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          scale: true,
          decay: 0.997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
      override_base_feature_extractor_hyperparams: true
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid_focal {
          alpha: 0.25
          gamma: 2.0
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    normalize_loc_loss_by_codesize: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
#  fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint:     "/foo/test/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03/model.ckpt"　　#チェックポイントを変更
  batch_size: 64
  sync_replicas: true
  startup_delay_steps: 0
  replicas_to_aggregate: 8
  num_steps: 25000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_crop_image {
      min_object_covered: 0.0
      min_aspect_ratio: 0.75
      max_aspect_ratio: 3.0
      min_area: 0.75
      max_area: 1.0
      overlap_thresh: 0.0
    }
  }
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        cosine_decay_learning_rate {
          learning_rate_base: .04
          total_steps: 25000
          warmup_learning_rate: .013333
          warmup_steps: 2000
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  max_number_of_boxes: 100
  unpad_groundtruth_tensors: false
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
#    input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/mscoco_train.record-00000-of-00100"
    input_path: "/foo/test/test_train.record"　　#独自訓練データに変更

  }
#  label_map_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt"
  label_map_path: "/foo/test/test_label_map.pbtxt"　　#独自クラス(2クラス)へ変更

}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  use_moving_averages: false
  num_examples: 8000
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
#    input_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/mscoco_val.record-00000-of-00010"
    input_path: "/foo/test/test_val.record"　　#独自検証データに変更
  }
#  label_map_path: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/mscoco_label_map.pbtxt"
  label_map_path: "/foo/test/test_label_map.pbtxt"　　#独自クラス(2クラス)へ変更
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

OOMが発生した類似の質問で「バッチサイズを小さくしなさい」
という指摘がありましたので、そちらを参考にして
上記configファイルの"batch_size"を64→32→16→...のよう
に小さくしていった場合、学習は開始されるようになりました。

```
train_config: {
#  fine_tune_checkpoint: "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/foo/test/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_shared_box_predictor_640x640_coco14_sync_2018_07_03/model.ckpt"　　#チェックポイントを変更
#  batch_size: 64
  batch_size: 4　　#サイズを4に変更
```

現状の環境で、この学習済モデルの設定を変更せずに実行させることは不可能なのでしょうか。

できる限り"batch_size: 64"にて実行したいと考えておりまして、
GPUを増設をしたりすれば実行できるようになるのでしょうか。
少しでも知見がある方がいらっしゃいましたら、教えていただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

実行環境
- OS：Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
- メモリ：31.3 GiB
- プロセッサ：Intel® Core™ i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 12
- GPU：GeForce GTX 1070 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

Answer (score 1):

oom_score_adj に値を書き込むことにより、特定のプロセスを OOM killer の対象外にできるようです。

[TIPS: 特定のプロセスをOOM Killerの対象から外す](https://users.atmark-techno.com/blog/1913/2767)

```
echo -1000 > /proc/<プロセスID>/oom_score_adj
```

Comment: @miwarin様　ご投稿いただきありがとうございます。教えていただいたURLを参考に、実行時のPythonプロセスをOOM Killerの対象外にすることはできました。しかし、その後Pythonのoom_scoreはずっと0となっていますが、「 Resource exhausted: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[100,51150] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc」というメッセージが出続けてしまいました。使用メモリが7292606874byte限界ギリギリまで達している様子です。

Comment: 一般的に、tensorflowでOOMが発生する原因はモデルのネットワークが大きい場合です。OOM Killterの対象から外すような対策は一般的には行われません。普通は、ネットワークサイズを減らすために、入力サイズやバッチサイズ、レイヤー、各レイヤーの次元等を減らすような対策を行います。